# Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a smallint

Tags: c#, .net

Quiero visualizar en un gridView los datos que saco de un procedimiento. Pero me salta el error de conversion de tipo de datos nvarchar a smallint.

```
protected void ddlCentrosTrabajo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmdResponsablesAreaTrabajo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_centroTrabajo", ddlCentrosTrabajo.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmdResponsablesAreaTrabajo.Connection = conexionCasa;
        conexionCasa.Open();
        daResponsableAreaTrabajo = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdResponsablesAreaTrabajo);
        cmdResponsablesAreaTrabajo.CommandText = ("cdt.pr_ResponsablesAreaTrabajo");
        cmdResponsablesAreaTrabajo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        daResponsableAreaTrabajo.Fill(dtResponsableAreaTrabajo);
        grdAreaTrabajo.DataSource = dtResponsableAreaTrabajo;
        grdAreaTrabajo.DataBind();
        conexionCasa.Close();
    }
```

Comment: El problema esta en la ejecución del procedimiento, comprueba que ddlCentrosTrabajo.SelectedItem.Value es un valor entero o es del tipo esperado por el parametro @p_centroTrabajo

Comment: Muchas gracias! Estaba mal el parámetro en el procedimiento. Un saludo.